# Error: unexpected '=' in when using "ifelse"

Tags: r

I want to create a new column based on a condition from two different columns in the df.
I'm using a nested "ifelse":

```
data_long$benchmark <- ifelse(data_long$axis1<=2 & data_long$axis2<=2, 1,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1>=3 & data_long$axis2=2, 2,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1=2 & data_long$axis2>=3, 2,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1=3 & data_long$axis2=3, 3,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1>=4 & data_long$axis2=3, 4,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1=3 & data_long$axis2>=4, 4,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1>=4 & data_long$axis2=4, 5,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1=4 & data_long$axis2>=4, 5,
                          ifelse(data_long$axis1>=5 & data_long$axis2>=5, 6)))))))))
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
> "data_long$benchmark <- ifelse(data_long$axis1<=2 & data_long$axis2<=2, "1",
> ifelse(data_long$axis1>=3 & data_long$axis2="

Comment: Please provide sample data with `dput(head(df,n))`. However, if you need these many ifelses, I personally think it may be time to rethink the whole data generation process. With sample data and a detailed explanation of the aim, it may be possible for someone to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: You have many typos in your code, eg. line 2 `data_long$axis2=2`, shoudl either be == or <= or >=. Same in many other lines.

Comment: The equal comparison syntax is `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct symbol for equality in R is `==`

Without some sample data, it's not possible to check all of your logic, but the error refers to the fact that you've used `=` within your `ifelse` statements.

So, for example, where you've used

```
...
ifelse(data_long$axis1>=3 & data_long$axis2=2, 2,
...
```

You should be using:

```
...
ifelse(data_long$axis1>=3 & data_long$axis2 == 2, 2,
...
```

Also, if you're nesting this many `ifelse` statements, I'd recommend looking at the `case_when` function in the `dplyr` package.